# finding out particular table from list of tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, select

How to select particular table to form the list of tables in oracle database? I tried with

```
select * from all_tables where table_name like 'table%'
```

but didn't get the desired output. There are hundreds of tables in database.

Comment: What output did you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow down your search by providing the owner of the table. The owner is the schema in which the table resides.

```
select owner,
       table_name 
from all_tables 
where table_name='table%'
and owner='MYOWNER';
```

Alternatively you can log into that particular schema and query user_tables.

```
select table_name 
from user_tables 
where table_name='table%';
```

Some background about owners, schemas and users in Oracle
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37012/difference-between-database-vs-user-vs-schema

Answer (score 0):

Data is stored in capital letters. Try

```
select * from all_tables where table_name like 'TABLE%';
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Table names can use mixed case, e.g. `"MyTable"`.

Answer (score 0):

In case your tables have case sensitive names (why?!) try:

```
select * from all_tables where UPPER(table_name) like 'TABLE%';
```